# How to resolve IllegalStateException when converting json to object?

Tags: json, jackson, illegalstateexception

I am trying to *convert Json to object using object mapper* `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper's readValue method`, but its throwing

> IllegalStateException saying problem: no suitable creator method found to deserialize from JSON String.

I have a Detail public `classOfferingTemplateDetail` which has 
`private List allPrices` as member with following getter setter methods.

```
public void setAllPrices(List<PriceListEntryDetail> allPrices){
    this.allPrices = allPrices;
}
public List getAllPrices(){
    return this.allPrices;
}
```

*`PriceListEntryDetail` is a public class `implementing Serializable` interface and default constructor*.

I am sending following json for `allPrices` attribute.

```
["List",
    [{
       "@type": "com.saba.pricing.PriceListEntryDetail",
       "amount": 10,
       "curr_id": {
                  "id": "crncy000000000000001",
                   "displayName": "Us Dollar"
                  }
    }]
]
```

Please help me to find out root cause. Thanks in advance.